# Removing "www" from a site URL

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

I need to remove the "www" part of a site's URL. Is it posible to simply go to settings and change both the Wordpress install URL? Or there's more steps involved? I'm a bit wary of changing the Wordpress install URL, I don't want ti to kick me out of my own install and not being able to access the site anymore but can i do it safely?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change your *WordPress Address (URL)* one option is to make use of this tool:
http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Just download it, upload it to your server, extract its files and access it via your browser.

**Example:**
Suppose your *WordPress Address (URL)* and your *Site Address (URL)* are "http://www.example.com" (without quotes obviously). So if you want to **remove "www"** I recommend you replace "www.example.com" with "example.com".
[image]

> Just make sure you first backup your database before doing anything and also before clicking on "live run" you should perform a "dry run".

Comment: I'll give it a try, if it works out well I'll accept your answer thank you. I've heard about this tool before.

Comment: Check my answer again. You saw it too quick and I've edited it.